Using Polars data in Django template html
lets start with their demo.
df = pl.DataFrame(
  {
    "foo": [1, 2, 3],
    "bar": [6, 7, 8],
  }
)
df.write_json()

'[{"foo":1,"bar":6},{"foo":2,"bar":7},{"foo":3,"bar":8}]'

I pass in the df in the from the df.write_json()
context = {

    'df' : df,
}

But nothing i am trying in Django is working?  the json was the only option i see to pass the data.
techinally this is a list of dicts?
<ul>
{% for i in df %}    # tried many option here

    {{ i.foo }}

{% endfor %}
<ul>

i have tried all sorts of things.
for Pandas i would just use df.to_records()
what is best way to get Polars data into a Django template to use in things like tables?
loving polars so far but getting confused by a few things.  Like this one.
Thanks!

is.   df.to_struct  the way to go? I seem to be getting data on the page?

you're not writing your html as you should. you need to insert <li> tags

the  was just an oversight here. it is on the site. sorry.

df.write_json() will produce a string, so you will enumerate over the characters, you should use .rows(named=True) [polars-doc]:
context = {
    'df': df.rows(named=True),
}

That's pandas. Op asked for a Polars solution.

@ritchie46: ah yes, than it is .row(named=True).
